# I get random numbers when I output string

Tags: c++

So I'm doing another task and I need your help. I made this program that should find a color and output a point's with that color coordinates and color. When I enter something like "raudona" (red) it outputs everything, but I get random numbers in between. When I enter "geltona" (yellow) it outputs just random numbers.

Here's the code:  (http://pastebin.com/YtN1vkFk — indented automatically with Uncrustify)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int CMax = 100;

struct taskai
{
    int x;
    int y;
    string spalva;
};
struct atrinkti
{
    int x;
    int y;
    string spalva;
};
// --------------------------------

void duomenys(taskai T[], int &n);
void isvedimas(taskai T[], atrinkti A[], int n, string ispal, int maxr);
void spalva(taskai T[], int n);
void atrinkimas(taskai T[], atrinkti A[], int n, string ispal, int &maxr);

// --------------------------------
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Lithuanian");
    string ispal;
    int n, maxr = 0;
    atrinkti A[CMax];
    taskai T[CMax];
    duomenys(T, n);
    cout << "Iveskite spalva:" << endl;
    cin >> ispal;
    atrinkimas(T, A, n, ispal, maxr);
    isvedimas(T, A, n, ispal, maxr);

    return 0;
}

void duomenys(taskai T[], int &n)
{
    ifstream duom("Duomenys.txt");

    duom >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        duom >> T[i].spalva;
        duom >> T[i].x >> T[i].y;
    }
}

void isvedimas(taskai T[], atrinkti A[], int n, string ispal, int maxr)
{
    ofstream ras("Rezultatai.txt");

    ras << "Pradiniai duomenys: " << endl;
    ras << endl;
    ras << setfill('-') << setw(40) << "-" << endl;
    ras << setfill(' ');
    ras << "Spalva" << setw(30) << "Koordinatės" << endl;
    ras << endl;
    ras << setfill('-') << setw(40) << "-" << endl;
    ras << setfill(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ras << setw(5) << T[i].spalva << setw(20) << T[i].x << setw(4) << T[i].y << endl;
    }
    ras << setfill('-') << setw(40) << "-" << endl;
    ras << setfill(' ');
    ras << endl;
    ras << setfill('_') << setw(40) << "_" << endl;
    ras << setfill(' ');
    ras << endl;
    ras << "Taškai, turintys spalvą " << ispal << " yra: " << endl;
    ras << endl;
    ras << "Koordinatės" << setw(15) << "Spalva" << endl;
    ras << setfill('_') << setw(40) << "_" << endl;
    ras << setfill(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxr; i++)
    {
        ras << setw(3) << A[i].x << setw(4) << A[i].y << setw(20) << A[i].spalva << endl;
    }
}

void atrinkimas(taskai T[], atrinkti A[], int n, string ispal, int &maxr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (ispal == T[i].spalva)
        {
            A[i].x = T[i].x;
            A[i].y = T[i].y;
            A[i].spalva = T[i].spalva;
            maxr++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the input file: (http://pastebin.com/3zvZgT8k)

```
5
raudona    -5 1
juoda       1 1
raudona    -4 3
geltona     5 5
geltona     6 6
```

First number is n, then there's colors and coordinates.

Comment: Please show a complete, short code example here.

Comment: It's better to inline the code here. If pastebin ever wents down, if just temporarily, your question becomes unusable. Also, read up on indendation first and make your code readable.

Comment: I know it's a bit messy, but I can't do much now..

Comment: If you can't do much, maybe we shouldn't do much to help you…after all, if it isn't important enough to you to make the code for the question comprehensible, it isn't important enough for us to spend time trying to fix the problems in it, either.

Comment: Have you printed out the data in `T` after the call to `duomenys()` to check whether the code read what you expected it to read?  Have you run the code under a debugger?  What have you done to try to analyze the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in `atrinkimas()`.

You use index `i` for two jobs simultaneously; you need two different counters (and the second is already in the code, called `maxr`):

```
void atrinkimas(taskai T[], atrinkti A[], int n, string ispal, int &maxr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (ispal == T[i].spalva)
        {
            A[maxr].x = T[i].x;
            A[maxr].y = T[i].y;
            A[maxr].spalva = T[i].spalva;
            maxr++;
        }
    }
}
```

As it was, you were copying material into the A array at not necessarily contiguous locations, leaving large numbers of the records uninitialized.  So, for example, with `raudona`, you were setting `A[0]` and `A[2]`, but subsequently trying to use `A[0]` and `A[1]`.  With `geltona`, you were setting `A[3]` and `A[4]`, but trying to use `A[0]` and `A[1]`.  So, the printing was using uninitialized values — not a recipe for happiness.